# How should I return reponse entity in Spring

Tags: java, spring, api

I found two ways to return a 201 request.

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build();
```

vs

```
return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
```

Which one is a better way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may annotate your method with `@ResponseStatus`

for example:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@PostMapping("/")
public void myMethod(){ }
```

documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseStatus.html